# do while loop to draw a square

Tags: java, do-while

int alto;
int ancho;

```
    System.out.println("Dame el alto: ");
    alto = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("dame el ancho: ");
    ancho = scanner.nextInt();

    int impresosAlto;
    int impresosAncho;

    do {
        impresosAlto = 0;
        impresosAncho = 0;

        do {

            System.out.print("*");

            impresosAncho++;

        } while (impresosAncho != ancho);

        System.out.println();

        impresosAlto++;

    } while (impresosAlto != alto);

    //

}
```

}

do while loop issue
Hi I´d like to sort this out but when i debug it , I have issues that the "impresosalto" stand whit int 1 instead of to , and the loop keep running in an infinite loop don´t know why , any help- advice ?
thanks
tried to change variables here and there but nothing worked out

Comment: You should move `impresosAlto = 0;` up one line.  If it's before the loop begins, it won't reset to zero every time the loop runs.  That way, the loop will eventually exit.

Comment: What @DawoodibnKareem said. Better yet, combine the assignment with the declaration above it, and move the declaration of `impresosAncho` into the loop.

Answer (score 3):

It is happening because your second condition of Alto is never reached, after every iteration impresosalto becomes zero. Put impresosalto=0 outside the loop and it will work fine

```
ImpresosAlto=0 move up two lines
```

Answer (score -1):

```java
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("height: ");
    final int height = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.print("width: ");
    final int width = scan.nextInt();

    int row = 1;

    do {
        int col = 1;

        do {
            boolean star = row == 1 || row == height || col == 1 || col == width;
            System.out.println(star ? '*' : ' ');
        } while (++col <= width);

        System.out.println();
    } while (++row <= height);
}
```

**Demo**

```
height: 4
width: 6
******
*    *
*    *
******
```